# I'm looking for a way to remove items from my select array based on values of other array

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, filter

I'm trying to remove from select array the options who match with my other array, both come from api and are beeing displayed through ngFor, i'm already trying to do it using filter but with no success, code below as follow:

```
  loadUnidadeUsuarios() {
    return this.restApi.getUnidadeUsuarios(this.id).subscribe((data: UnidadeUsuario) => {
      this.unidadeUsuarioData = data;
    });
  }
```

Then after load UnidadeUsuarioData i need to remove the users who match:

```
 loadUsuarios() {
    return this.restApi.getUsuarios().subscribe((data: Usuario) => {
    this.Usuario = data;

    this.Usuario = this.Usuario.filter(usuario => usuario.id !== this.unidadeUsuarioData.id )
    });
 }
```

But with no success

Comment: can you add console.log of data line below this.Usuario = data; and share that output

Comment: you need to run on both arrays

Comment: and this.unidadeUsuarioData ouput also

Comment: yes i need to run both arrays

Comment: but i don't know why

Comment: the this.unidadeUsuarioData.id returns undefined, need to loop through it as well

Comment: run both arrays, compare them and remove who match, sounds simple but i cant ):

Comment: try this.unidadeUsuarioData[0].id ... undefined because this.unidadeUsuarioData seems to be an array and not object, console logs will help to debug the issue

Comment: Could it be your typing?
".subscribe((data: Usuario)" to ".subscribe((data: Usuario[]) "

Comment: try this.unidadeUsuarioData[0].id i know it works but i need to loop through it to compare

Comment: the type is correct, is an array of objects

Comment: Array of objects typing = usuario[]
single object typing = usuario

Answer (score 0):

the filter it's looks like

```
this.Usuario.filter(usuario=>!this.unidadeUsuario.find(x=>x.id==usuario.id)
```

But you must take account if you need wait to the two calls finish. For this use switchMap

```
this.restApi.getUnidadeUsuarios(this.id).pipe(
  switchMap((res: any[]) => {
    //..here you has your getUnidadeUsuario...
    //but you want the others usuarios
    return this.restApi.getUsuarios().pipe(map((usuarios: any[]) => {
      //in usuarios you has all the usuarios
      //but you want filtered
      return usuarios.filter(u => !res.find(x => x.id == u.id))
    }))
  })
).subscribe(usuarios => {
  console.log(usuarios)
})
```

Comment: Argument of type 'OperatorFunction<any[], unknown>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'OperatorFunction<UnidadeUsuario, unknown>

Answer (score 0):

To achieve expected result, with just two loops, use below option

1. Convert unidadeUsuarioData as obj with id values
2. Filter Usuario to check whether unidadeUsuarioData has property id

`loadUsuarios() {
        let unidadeUsuarioDataObj = this.unidadeUsuarioData.reduce((acc, v) => {
        acc[v.id] = v;
        return acc
      }, {})
        this.Usuario = this.Usuario.filter(usuario => !unidadeUsuarioDataObj[usuario.id])
        console.log(this.Usuario)
     }`

stackblitz for reference- https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dapycb?file=src/app/app.component.html

Comment: it's returning the same array as the beginning when i apply it

Comment: Did you try my stackblitz ?? Click filter button to run that method